# Linux modules for PC speaker: pcspkr vs snd_pcsp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, kernel-modules

What is the difference between these two modules

- `pcspkr`: PC-Speaker driver
- `snd_pcsp`: PC-Speaker driver

different tutorials call for different ones

Comment: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SND_PCSP.html : seems it (tries to) turn(s) the pc speaker into a sound card (with a sound card API), with beep left as a bonus.

Comment: are either of these modules deprecated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pcspkr` is the standard module; it allows you to control the PC speaker via the input layer. The canonical symlink is `/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr`. You can *send* events to the speaker by writing to it (most other input devices will produce events, which you *read* from the input device node). The PC speaker is very simple, basically it can play tones of a given frequency, which can be used for beeps with different pitches.

`snd_pcsp` is an attempt to the use this very limited hardware to produce full PCM sound. It appears as an ALSA device. It doesn't work very well, at least on my system; the sound is barely recognizable. I'd by surprised if a "tutorial calls for it".

Comment: If the question is "how do I get virtualbox to simulate a PC speaker" (which you didn't mention at all in the question above, might be a good idea to do it next time): As you've already heard, either enable virtualbox to directly access the speaker hardware via passthrough, or use whatever options virtualbox has to emulate a speaker. (I haven't tried either). Read virtualbox docs for details. If virtualbox doesn't emulate enough for you, try QEMU. Linux modules on the host side have nothing to do with this.